# How to get projects from Visual SourceSafe using SourceSafe Interop?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, interop, visual-sourcesafe

My company is still using SourceSafe as source control. I'd like to create a C# app for tracking versions of projects on SourceSafe (plus some additional info).

I've been searching the internet for tutorials on SourceSafe Interop, but couldn't find any.

Does anyone know how to use that thing and get projects and files in it? Not by string as it is described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.visualstudio.sourcesafe.interop.ivssitem.version(v=vs.80).aspx).

Comment: You mean like the code example that is on the page you linked?

Comment: @JohnKoerner - as I said above, not like that. I meant to search them from some kind of collection which I can't find.